# Style DatePicker Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using native DatePicker for android but I need to style its colors to be something like this[image]

instead of the native one

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/from_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="true"
        android:spinnersShown="false"
        >
    </DatePicker>
```

Comment: Please look into the system styles there should be something like android:datePickerStyle then you override the styles like you want. However keep in mind that some colors are hardcoded for some devices like the divider of NumberPicker. A good point to start is also the source code of that view.